# Modern Warfare 3: Viewing stats online

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, xbox-360

Is there anyway to view Modern Warfare 3 stats (such as KD, level, etc) online (via a browser, not using the in game options)? I'm particularly interested in something for Xbox 360.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I remember huge talks about a premium subscription mode for *CoD*, and this is the most basic of features I'd expect if I paid a subscription. (not that I would).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Call of Duty Elite](http://www.callofduty.com/elite/whats-included) page, on which you can sign up for free and get the following:

> 1. PERSONAL Call of Duty® CAREER PROFILE
>
>    Track thousands of gameplay stats, personal bests, & trends across Call of Duty® Black Ops, MW3 & all future enabled Call of Duty® games.
>
>    - Career Stats
>    - Recent Match Summaries
>    - Performance Tracking
>    - Create Custom Leaderboards
>    - Showcase Trophies & Winnings
>    - Spec Ops Stats
>    - Private Match Data
>    - News Feed
>    - Notifications / Activity
>    - Facebook Friend Import

You can find videos and screenshots of the Call of Duty Elite service.  For example, a screenshot from the beta provides the data you're looking for:

[image: Call of Duty Elite feature screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found is to compare with another player. Search for a player by name, then on the top right, click Compare.